# express.js :"Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

a question which was often discussed(error message: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object) , but the answers in the other feeds does'nt work. e.g.

```
app.use(app.router);
routes.initialize(app);
```

This code brings the message: 
throw new Error('\'app.router\' is deprecated!\nPlease see the 3.x to 4.x
migration guide for details on how to update your app.');
      ^
Error: 'app.router' is deprecated!
Please see the 3.x to 4.x migration guide for details on how to update your app.

I hope there will be a better idea.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbname');
//var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

//Init App
var app = express();

//View Engine
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set('view engine','handlebars');


//BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
app.use(urlencodedParser);
app.use(cookieParser());


//Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

//Express Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

//Passprt init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

//Connect Flash
app.use(flash());

//Global Vars
app.use(function(req,res, next) {
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('succes_msg');
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    next();
});

//Set Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));

// Set Port
app.set('port',(process.env.PORT || 3000));

//Start Server
app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Server started on port '+app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Well, *which* line is it complaining about? It should show you in the stack trace...

Comment: Desktop\master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js :458
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a '
 + gettype(fn));
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.use (Desktop\master\node_modules\expres
s\lib\router\index.js:458:13)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (Desktop\master\node_mo
dules\express\lib\application.js:219:21)

Comment: If the stack trace doesn't contain an entry for your own code, then start selectively commenting out middleware until the error disappears. I suspect it may be your routes. Perhaps you might want to include their code as well in your question.